# How can I get the "path" of a key in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array = ["farm"=>
              [
                "horse"=>
                 [
                  "horseman"=>
                     [
                      "fred1"=>  "fred1",
                      "fred2"=> "fred2",
                      "fred3"=>"fred3",
                      "fred4"=>  "fred4"
                    ],
                 "horseman2"=>
                    ["john"=> "john"]
                  ]  
              ]
    ];
```

And I am searching in this array for a specific key:

```
    function findKey($array, $keySearch) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
      $basePath = $basePath === null ? $key : $basePath. "/" . $key;
        if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false){
        echo "<li>Path:".$basePath."</li>"; 
            echo "<li>".$key."</li>";
         }   
        if (is_array($item))
           findKey($item, $keySearch); 
    }
}

findKey($array, 'horse');
```

What I need is simply the "paths" of my resulted keys.

But my result is:

Path:horse

horse

Path:horseman

horseman

https://eval.in/564230

I tried so many ways, but I cannot achieve what I need :(

---

Here some examples:

```
 findKey($array, 'horse');
```

Path:farm

horse

Path:farm/horse

horseman

Path:farm/horse

horseman2

```
findKey($array, 'horseman');
```

Path:farm/horse

horseman

Path:farm/horse

horseman2

```
findKey($array, 'horseman2');
```

Path:farm/horse

horseman2

Comment: wonderful thinking....

Comment: you need to assign `basepath` as global.

Comment: Your answer is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this function**

Check the Script online [Script](https://eval.in/564550).

> Because you call the same function again and again, so you lost the
>   value of `basepath`. So pass this every time you call the function.

```
function findKey($array, $keySearch, $basePath) {
    $basePath2 = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        $basePath = ($basePath == "") ? $key : $basePath. "/" . $key;
        if($key == $keySearch){
            if(is_array($item)){
                foreach($item as $key2 => $value){
                    $basePath2 = ($basePath2 == "") ? $key : $basePath2. "/" . $key;
                    echo "<li>Path:".$basePath."</li>"; 
                    echo "<li>".$key2."</li>";
                }
            }           
            break;
        }else{
            if(is_array($item)){
                foreach($item as $key3 => $value3){
                    echo "<li>Path:".$basePath."</li>";
                    echo "<li>".$key3."</li>";
                }               
            }
        }

        if(is_array($item))
            findKey($item, $keySearch, $basePath);
    }
}
findKey($array, 'horse', '');
```

**Result**

- Path:farm
- horse
- Path:farm/horse
- horseman
- Path:farm/horse
- horseman2

Comment: Thank you! Awesome! :) I am so happy!!

Comment: I tested it with my code, but I found there is some trouble if I have multiple key results in one dimension, example: https://eval.in/564281

Comment: The path for `horseman2` should be also `Path:farm/horse` but here it is `Path:farm/horse/horseman`

Comment: @jarla, I stuck on it. may be need more time, i will check and let you know when i was free.

Comment: Great! It is working now very well! How can I honor you for your work? Is there something I can do? You really helped me so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110953/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-jarla).

Comment: Just one little issue, if I search for horseman2 your new code is also making the output `john` and `fred` for example. So `horseman2` should only have one output. https://eval.in/564550

Comment: you use `horseman2` for searching, so all the upper level child must include to output.

Comment: If the searching is `horseman2` the result needs to be only `<li>Path:farm/horse</li><li>horseman2</li>`

Comment: because `horseman2`  is the only key that includes `horseman2`

Comment: I think I found the solution: What do you think: https://eval.in/564989

Comment: Yes, perfectly done.